# How do I detect a Word table with (horizontally) merged cells?

Tags: vba, ms-word

When a Word table contains horizontally merged cells, accessing aTable.Columns.First or performing a For Each over aTable.Columns will result in an error.

Is there a way to determine if a table contains horizontally merged cells without resulting in an error?

I've read [Determine if a Word cell is merged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269545/determine-if-a-word-cell-is-merged), but that is about detecting if a particular Word table cell is merged, rather than does the whole table have any merged cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a reference in [this article](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/Table_Cell_Data.htm) to a Uniform property on the Table object, which will return a false if the table has merged or split cells.

Though this does not indicate if the cells are horizontally or vertically merged (or both), but it's a start, and the property answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's there.
                Here is the logical explanation how you will detect vertically merged cells. Horizontally merged cell also can detect, but it will need some more coding.

```
            But, unfortunately, not by calling any WORD VBA method or accessing any property of cell or table. It's by applying successive steps.

            Step1:
            -> Detect Row Count and Column Count of the table

            Step2:
            -> Declare an string array with same dimension as table( Dim A$()). Fill each cell of the array with "<m>" string.

            Step3:
            -> Start from cell(1)
            -> Then move cell by cell(Cell.Next method)
            -> Get each cells RowIndex and ColumnIndex.
            -> Erase the content "<m>" from the array, referenced by this RowIndex and ColumnIndex(A(RowIndex,ColumnIndex)=""
            -> Repeat this step until Cell.Next ends.

            Step4:
            -> Now check each cell of the Array(A$()). Those cells have the"<m>" string, are merged. Merged with immediate top cell. 

            I've not placed any function or code block. Assume it'll be more easy.

            Thanks

            Shubhayan
```